# How to achieve a toggle effect to individual ion-card?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, toggle, card

Current issue : Whenever I am changing toggle, change-effect applying on every ion card.
Expected : I want to achieve a toggle effect individually on ion-card.

HTML :

```
 <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col *ngFor="let device of individual_room.devices">
            <ion-card>
                <ion-col><img src="assets/icon/favicon.png"/></ion-col>
                <ion-card-content>
                <ion-card-title>
                    {{ device.name }} <ion-badge item-end>{{ device.company }} </ion-badge>
                </ion-card-title>
                <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="deviceStatus" (ionChange)="deviceStatusChange()"></ion-toggle>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

CSS :

```
ion-card {
    --background:#262626;
    height: 150px;
    width: 80% !important;
}

ion-toggle[aria-checked="false"]{
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
   &::before {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     font-size: 10px;
     line-height: 10px;
   }
   &::after {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
   }
  }
  ion-toggle[aria-checked="true"]{
   position: relative;
   width: 60px;
   &::before {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
   }
  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 3px;
    color: #fff;
  }
 }
```

TS file :

```
const TOKEN_KEY = 'CapacitorStorage.user-token'
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tabhome',
    templateUrl: './tabhome.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tabhome.page.scss'],
})
export class TabhomePage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    
    public deviceStatus:boolean = true;
    ngOnInit() {

        // locally provided json file
          fetch('./assets/data/tabHomeData.json').then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
           this.data = res
          });

        const headerHeight = isPlatform('ios') ? 44 : 56
        this.document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
            '--header-position',
            `calc(env(safe-area-inset-top) + ${headerHeight}px)`
        )
    }

    deviceStatusChange(){
        console.log("device toggle switch : "+this.deviceStatus);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.lists.changes.subscribe((_) => {
            this.listElements = this.lists.toArray()
        })
    }
```

tabHomeData.json :

```
{
    "user": "Ram",
    "rooms": [
        {
            "name": "LIVING ROOM",
            "devices": [
                {
                    "name": "fan",
                    "type": "FAN",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "ON",
                    "speed": 100
                },
                {
                    "name": "bulb",
                    "type": "BULB",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "ON",
                    "colour": "WHITE"
                },
        {
                    "name": "Hall TV",
                    "type": "TV",
                    "company": "Redmi",
                    "state": "OFF"
                },
        {
                    "name": "AC",
                    "type": "AC",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "ON",
                    "colour": "WHITE"
                },
        {
                    "name": "bulb",
                    "type": "BULB",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "ON",
                    "colour": "WHITE"
                },
        {
                    "name": "bulb",
                    "type": "BULB",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "ON",
                    "colour": "WHITE"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Kitchen",
            "devices": [
                {
                    "name": "fan",
                    "type": "FAN",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "OFF",
                    "speed": 50
                },
                {
                    "name": "bulb",
                    "type": "BULB",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "OFF",
                    "colour": "YELLOW"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BED ROOM",
            "devices": [
                {
                    "name": "fan",
                    "type": "FAN",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "OFF",
                    "speed": 50
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "WASH ROOM",
            "devices": [
                {
                    "name": "exast",
                    "type": "FAN",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "OFF"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bulb",
                    "type": "BULB",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "OFF",
                    "colour": "YELLOW"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bulb",
                    "type": "BULB",
                    "company": "Philips",
                    "state": "ON",
                    "colour": "WHITE"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In HTML file through json file in a loop , I am trying to set every device in a cardView. And want to use toggle for each card separately.

Please find below attached screenshot :

[image: All toggle switches changing for all cards]

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to achieve the toggle on the ion-card, below is one way to achieve it:

1. use the state property on your json to manage the toggle state of the toggle component on the card
2. modify your toggle component like so:

   <ion-toggle (click)="deviceStatusChange(device)"
   [checked]="device.state =='ON'">
3. Add toggle state change to the deviceStatusChangeMethod

   public deviceStatusChange(device:any) {
   device.state = (device.state === 'ON') ? 'OFF' : 'ON';
   }

Comment: Hello lee,
After implementing these steps, first time toggle doesn't working. Suppose initially toggle is in ON mode. After clicking on toggle in UI ,in logs I can see it's printing OFF but on UI it's still in ON mode. second time on UI toggle goes in OFF mode but that time in logs device state is ON. Can you please help me in this issue?

Comment: @PriteshBhate do you want to add your code here ? If so, I can take a peek and see if something stands out. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-js46vd?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts